# Blow up along a section of a smooth morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, blow-ups, smoothness, complete-intersection

Let $C$ be a ground locally notherian and quasiprojective scheme. Let $\pi:S\to B$ be a $C$-morphism of finite type $C$-schemes. We call $\pi$ a $C$-smooth morphism if the morphisms $S\to C$ and $B\to C$ are smooth.

My question is (edited by @Ben's comment): Given a $C$-section $\sigma:B \to S$ of $\pi$ and the blow up $b:\tilde S\to S$ of $S$ along $\sigma(B)$, is the morphism $\tilde \pi:= \pi\circ b:\tilde S\to B$ smooth or at least $C$-smooth?

In **Intersection theory** of *W.Fulton* there are referents to EGA to see that $\sigma$ is local complete intersection morphism.

I'm asking for some kind of generalization of Theorem 22.3.10 (if $X\to Y$ is a closed embedding of smooth varieties over k, then $Bl_XY$ is smooth) in [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjan2915public.pdf) to a ground scheme $C$.

Comment: Take $B=C=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$, $k$ algebraically closed, and e.g. $S=\mathbb{P}^2$. You are asking  whether the blow up morphism of a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is smooth. I hope you realize this is completely false.

Comment: Isn't $\tilde{\pi}$ just the map to $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your coment @abx, I edited my question. I'm sorry.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32396/good-reduction-and-blow-ups